# Local search algorithm, complete confusion

Tags: search, traveling-salesman

In (a) and (b), assuming a 2-exchange transformation operator, connect solutions A and B, which are TSP tours in path representation, to their possible neighbors among tours C, D, E, F, G

```
(a) A: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

C: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6
D: 1 2 5 4 3 6 7
E: 2 3 1 7 5 4 6
F: 4 1 7 5 3 2 6
G: 1 2 3 7 6 5 4

(b) B: 1 3 2 7 5 4 6

C: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6
D: 1 2 5 4 3 6 7
E: 2 3 1 7 5 4 6
F: 4 1 7 5 3 2 6
G: 1 2 3 7 6 5 4
```

I have no clue what this is asking me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definitions** (inferred from the problem text, maybe you discussed this in class too) 
*TSP tour in path representation*:
   An ordered sequence of the digits 1 thru 7, each digit cited once and only once.
   Each digit represents a city visited by the Traveling Salesperson.
   For example  D: `1 2 5 4 3 6 7`,  indicates that Salesperson starts in city 1, goes  to city2,
   then city 5...  and ends in city 7.
It is probably useful at this point to introduce the concept of a 'stop' and to label these with ***lowercase*** letters, a trhu g. (no relation at all with the uppercase letters used to identify various paths in the problem).
In the D path, the a stop is city 1,  the c stop is city 5 etc.

*a 2-exchange transformation operator*
   An operation which transforms a TSP path by exchanging exactly two cities (or, more precisely, by swapping the city for two of the stops).
A 2-exchange Transformation operation can therefore be understood as an operation which takes three arguments: a Path X, two stop indexes m,n, and returns the path X' where the cities at m and n have been swaped.
If we call this operation Swp(), we can write

```
   Swp(A, c, e) = 1 2 5 4 3 6 7
```

**The assignment** (Your mission, would you accept it ;-) )
*connect solutions A and B, which are TSP tours in path representation, to their possible neighbors among tours C, D, E, F, G*
I'm guessing the requirement it is to identify among C,D, E F and G (upper case i.e. the Paths) which are "neighbor" paths of A (or of B), i.e. which of these can be derived from A (or from B) with a single Swp() operation  (and probably to provide the said operation parameters).

By extension one may interpret the assignment as one where one needs to find *a* (not *the* as there may be several) list of Swp() operations needed to go from A to another path, in a minimal number of steps.